# rowSelect event returns null when multiple datatables are rendered

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a composite component with a lazily loaded datatable. I need to render this component multiple times on the same page. I need to enable single row selection on the tables as well. The problem is that in the rowSelect event, only the table that is rendered last on the page returns the selected object, other tables return null.

Component kwe:lazytable:

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="bean" required="true" />
    <composite:attribute name="groupId" required="true" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>        
    <p:dataTable id="entityTable" widgetVar="entityTable" var="entity" value="#{cc.attrs.bean.loadEntities(cc.attrs.groupId)}" 
                 rows="5" resizableColumns="true" lazy="true" selectionMode="single">
        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{cc.attrs.bean.onRowSelect}" />
        ...
    </p:dataTable>
</composite:implementation>
```

Rendered multiple times:

```
<kwe:lazytable bean="#{cc.attrs.bean}" groupId="#{1}" />
<kwe:lazytable bean="#{cc.attrs.bean}" groupId="#{2}" />
<kwe:lazytable bean="#{cc.attrs.bean}" groupId="#{3}" />
```

In the backing bean, LazyDataModels are stored in a map:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SearchBean {
    private Map<Integer, LazyEntitiesDataModel> lazyEntitiesMap = new HashMap<>();

    public LazyDataModel<T> loadEntities(int groupId) {
        LazyEntitiesDataModel entities = lazyEntitiesMap.get(groupId);
        if (entities == null) {
            entities = new LazyEntitiesDataModel();
            lazyEntitiesMap.put(groupId, entities);
        }
        return entities;
    }

    public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event.getObject());
    }
}
```

The same thing happens if a I put `selection="#{cc.attrs.bean.selectedentity}"` in the datatable declaration. It is only populated when selecting a row from the last table.

Does anybody have an idea of why this does not work?

Comment: when you tried using an attribute for the selected entity, did you use one attribute for each table, or the same one for all of them?

Comment: It was the same attribute for all the tables. The tables are rendered in a cycle, so I would need to do a parametrized binding of the selectedEntity somehow.